# Relation of linear models

Tags: mathematical-modeling, time-series

Let's assume that
\begin{equation}
Y_t -Y_{t-1} = \beta(X_t - X_{t-1}) + \alpha + \varepsilon_t
\end{equation}

where $Y_t -Y_{t-1}$, $X_t-X_{t-1}$, $\varepsilon_t$ fulfill all assumptions of linear regression model.

Does such relation always imply that $Y_t$ has a trend, i.e.
$Y_t = \beta X_t + \alpha t + \gamma + \varepsilon_t'$?

All I came to is that the opposite relation always holds.